# from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to create a word document with Python.
I did pip install python-docx in my terminal.

My code looks like this:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.save('Test.docx')
```

I could not create a new document. What am I missing? The existing answer to install python-docx did not work for me.

```
from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

Comment: python version? It works till python 3.4 https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/ Check programming language section

Comment: I have python 3.6.3 installed and python-docx version is python-docx-0.8.7
What python-docx version should i install?

Comment: Install Python 3.4

Comment: Nowdays that link mentions python 3.8, and just tested python-docx with 3.9, works fine.

Answer (score 10):

you need to install

> "python-docx"

by

```
pip install python-docx
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall docx if installed

   ```
   pip uninstall docx
   ```
2. Install python-docx

   ```
   pip install python-docx
   ```
3. Import docx

   ```
   import docx
   ```
4. Import Document from docx

   ```
   from docx import Document
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip freeze` and check whether the module name is listed or not.